# How to integrate bootstrap from NPM in React application?

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, npm, reactjs

I'm building a React application and would like to use Bootstrap in it. Therefore I'm using the package `bootstrap-react`. Bootstrap's CSS has to be integrated in the index.html. Currently I've got this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
```

I would like to use it directly from npm (https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap) but don't know how to reference it. I could copy it via Gulp but is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**webpack**

If you are using [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/), you can use the [style-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/style-loader) to `require()` the CSS file directly.

**SASS**

If you are using SASS, you can install [bootstrap-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-sass) and import the file directly from `node_modules` into your scss file

```
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
```

I've had the most success with these two options.  You can probably do the same thing with `Less`, although Bootstrap just announced they were switching to SASS, so you might want to switch anyway.